# TypeError when logging kwargs

Tags: python, django-class-based-views

I am getting TypeError while logging kwargs and args. Below is the base class of Django View class I am using to log kwargs.

```
class CustomAPI(APIView):
    _url = None

    def initial(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logger.info("Request: %s, Args: %s, Kwargs: %s" % (request.__dict__, str(*args), str(**kwargs)))
        CustomAPI._url = request.get_full_path()
        super(CustomAPI, self).initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The error logs show the following error-

> File "path/to/app/api_common.py", line 55, in initial
>       logger.info("Request: %s, Args: %s, Kwargs: %s" % (request.**dict**, str(*args), str(**kwargs)))
>   TypeError: 'id' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

is something wrong with str(**kwargs)?

Comment: What is the `CustomAPI` class? Are you certain that the request is being handled by the `APIProductDetails` class and that it isn't matching a different URL pattern? Please show the full traceback.

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks for pointing it. Yes, CustomAPI was causing the error. But I am still confused why it is occurring. Have added the details in the code. If I am commenting the logger line, it is working fine.

Comment: As an aside, `CustomApi._url` is not thread safe - if you read back `CustomApi._url` later, you might see a value that was written by another request. It should be safe to set `self._url` and read back `self._url` later.

Comment: Thanks for pointing. Will review this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you have `str(**kwargs)`. If `kwargs` is `{'id': '5'}`, this is equivalent to `str(id=5)`, which raises a `TypeError` because `str` does not accept `id`.

If you want the string representation of the `kwargs` dict, then use:

```
str(kwargs)
```

Similarly, `str(*args)` will give a TypeError if `len(args) > 1`. You should use:

```
str(args)
```

Answer (score -1):

You should access the arguments via `self.kwargs` not `kwargs` of the method.

Django does not actually call your method in a direct approach. Since it creates the class instance on the fly, the `kwargs` are not accessed as you do in function based views. DRF views are nothing but Django generic view, so the rule apply for them as well.

Answer (score -1):

or you can pass id in method

```
class APIProductDetails(CustomAPI):

    permission_classes = (CustomAuthentication,)

    def get(self, request, id):
        return Response(data={}, status=200)
```